# Unity3d WebView.dll not found

Tags: webview, unity-game-engine

Trying to implement [unity-webview](https://github.com/gree/unity-webview) in Unity. But I get a WebView DllNotFoundException and I can't seem to find the dll anywhere in the source to link to it. Anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to implement touch scroll functionality but I'd like to be able to find the dll to decompile it or at least get a function listing. The update function being called is pretty limited.

Comment: nope, sorry. But based on Kazuki's answer below I think it might be caused by the default build/test environment on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to find the dll anywhere in the source to link to it

You mean you are going to use it for Windows? unity-webview supports only Android, iOS, OS X, and WebPlayer.